# Rails 3.1 engine rake db:test:prepare task missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working on a rails 3.1 engine, and as it's a brand new release and I'm working off of edge, I didn't expect things to go perfectly. I can't seem to get my engine to see the db:test:prepare task when I run bundle exec rake -T

I'm using rake 0.8.7 and edge rails. If I try to require the dummy application's Rakefile, I get

`undefined method 'prerequisites' for nil:NilClass`
 on line 7 of spec/dummy/Rakefile

Line 7 of my Rakefile in spec/dummy/ is `Dummy::Application.load_tasks`

My research so far has brought me to http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/rails-3-beta-is-out-a-retrospective/ which corresponds with [databases.rake](https://github.com/rails/rails/raw/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake) in Active Record.

How do I get the `db:test:prepare` task into my engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2011/05/22/rspec-rails-261beta1-is-released/ is the answer.

The reason being is that it guards against calling prerequisites on nil and will work with Rails 3.1 RC (or edge at this moment in time).

Comment: Brilliant @Omar. The timing of these posts are insane. Rails 3.1 gets lauched, I fiddle with it, a few hours later the fix pops up in a blog post. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I think you have to prefix with `app`, so `rake app:db:test:prepare`, or just `rake app:test:prepare`.

Comment: Thanks Kris, I just needed it today, was surprised when I saw who post the proper answer. Best, Aleks from Warsaw :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, then it's just called rake test:prepare in rails 3.1

Comment: It's called that, but how do I get that task into my engine? It's currently sitting in Active Record, and my dummy app Rakefile gives an error when I try to load it. So I can't really get the task.